Wallets transformed into token accounts and drained
I am not a developer but I work in the ecosystem and I've been seeing reports from users about their wallets being turned into token accounts and then drained.
I'm sharing below one of a few examples I've seen, and it seems someone is managing to somehow transform wallet addresses into their own Token Account and transfer funds out via that method. This also prevents the original wallet owner from doing any transactions.
Example case:
This user got his wallet turned into a token account over a month ago, and since then everything he sends to that wallet is drained, and he can't make any transactions with it.
Wallet: E3GdLdbgsuGxLxHAL1hE7Q3hdGgUoDx6e92YRv779Nt8, and it was later made a token account of the wallet D9LkdPS7eUrD96EnqY5JBQmWwPKrk71ShtvdFv7k29Ua
Elaborating:
You can see in the "Transactions" tab and in the "Balance Changes" tab that this wallet (E3GdLdbgsuGxLxHAL1hE7Q3hdGgUoDx6e92YRv779Nt8) is not a new wallet, in this transaction for example https://solscan.io/tx/37ZUiGyyZ2kHRmzxhX1NyiozGWxzjejtGdZsjQygx3Vx76MH1Xh7NHmXV4jAcSQvBp7EVhgm1bWzstUBRQUoM1BX you can see the wallet closing another token account over 1 year ago, which both shows it's not a new account and shows it's not a token account itself, instead being a wallet. It also held multiple tokens (and had associated token accounts), and held NFTs.
It seems this other transaction https://solscan.io/tx/23L8PhMc4DCc4akwz5KyhwokDCASuZ5k6ZxS338VNa6R8TXbAKYRQP21f619JaVa7omyYYkaHH26E68gXDpZorM6 is when the Wallet "D9LkdPS7eUrD96EnqY5JBQmWwPKrk71ShtvdFv7k29Ua" turns "E3GdLdbgsuGxLxHAL1hE7Q3hdGgUoDx6e92YRv779Nt8" into a token account.
I found one other similar case in My account has become a Token Account, how can I solve it? but the user didn't follow up or didn't give many details, but checking his wallet it seems to be a similar situation, so I'm trying to detail it as much as I can in this post.
I've also seen this happen to other people with their wallet addresses being turned into Token Accounts and being drained and turned unusable.
Is this an exploit? Is Solana Foundation aware of this? It really got me worried (I hold most of my funds in Solana) as I've seen this happen to multiple people and I've seen big funds being stolen, so I wanted to check if anyone has any insight into this and how this could've been possible, as well as if other wallets are safe from this type of exploit/action.

this is actually a very interesting case.
you're right that this address is a token account, and used to be a wallet address before. The transaction you sent is indeed transforming this address into a token account. Although, you can see that E3Gd... signed this transaction. So this can't happen randomly to your wallet, as long as you don't sign random transactions, you're safe.
There is one thing i don't get tho: what is the point of making this address a token account? Might be to "protect the hacker", because by transforming the account to a token account, no other wallet can do anything anymore for this account... interested in other people point of view on this

This thing is true, it happened with my account. Here is the transaction details.
https://solscan.io/tx/5a4KXU6oJngy5kNW1qppjLEvR9Sc5yXmTRiCnXbADRdD9dj1pAFMjwcwSVvoM9j8WDvMGkbYWb4pMwnYxYkok4qA
At first they sent 0.0029 sol to your account a few times. when you transfer balance to your account they drain it right away.

here is my account. they transformed it to Token account :
https://solscan.io/account/J6XHoatXq1thecNCDirNZ9UuvF8irn6zE4ujsSUNWkTf
all of my assets are stolen and transferrer to this address :
D9LkdPS7eUrD96EnqY5JBQmWwPKrk71ShtvdFv7k29Ua
